# ¿Como leer un csv con PHP y no repetir los datos en MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un archivo .csv con las posiciones de un objeto móvil. Cada determinado tiempo se actualiza la posición del objeto y registra una nueva posición.

Quiero leer el .csv a cada intervalo de tiempo para introducir los datos en una tabla mysql, pero como leo todo el .csv, si registro un campo autoincremental, me multiplica los datos por cada lectura del .csv introduciendo no solo el nuevo valor sino los anteriores.

¿Como puedo hacer para saltar los datos ya registrados en la tabla y leer solo los nuevos del .csv?

Comment: Has probado con la funcion `fgetcsv`, al inicio de la lectura puedes obtener la cantidad de campos insertados en la tabla, y saltarte esa cantidad(no hacerles insert), una vez pasado esa cantidad comienzas a insertar hasta el final del csv

Comment: Se me ocurre hacer una fila PRIMARY KEY con una combinación de dos o tres columnas, de manera que sea un número único. Y que cuando vuelva a leerlo se salte el valor

Comment: no, porque puede ser los puntos(posiciones) que insertes puedan repetirse, y si los saltas habra algo "raro".

Comment: Que tal esto: buscar un ID único, con las columnas DATETIME y LATITUD, si es necesario se utiliza otra mas.                           
$dateTime =   "2017-02-19 11:14:00";
$l = 46.9921500;
$L = -9.1631180;
$ID =  $l*1000000000 + strtotime($dateTime);
                                                                                                                                    por ejemplo; ID = 48479649240

Comment: esta bien lo que piensas, pero en el momento en el que tenga que recorrer muchos datos del principio, ***lo que estas intentando hacer es un insert con columnas repetidas, dado eso el motor intenta realizar la insercción primero buscando que todos los datos no coincidan, por cada uno que intentes insertar***

Comment: Si pruebas a introducir una columna autoincremental ID (integer) dentro del csv  y la tabla de mysql para cada nuevo registro, podrías controlar perfectamente cual es el nuevo campo a insertar, siempre sería el siguiente ID al último que te devuelva la BD.